# Dropdown values are same in 4 fields, when i'm selecting the first dropdown it selects correctly for second dropdown it's again updating in

Tags: java, selenium

I want to select dropdown values e.g: country dropdown, i'm having 4  dropdown fields, when i select the first dropdown,values are selected, for the second dropdown the values are updating in first dropdown not in second.

```
if(!dropdownname.isEmpty() && dropdownname.equals("Country of Residence")) {

   utilfile.waitForNodeLoad();

   String selectdropdown2 = Appendix2FormXpathLoader.getDropDownXpath(dropdownname);
   WebElement clickdropdown2 = findBy(selectdropdown2);
   withAction().moveToElement(clickdropdown2);
   clickdropdown2.click();
   String selectdropdownvalue1 = Appendix2FormXpathLoader.getDropDownValueXpath(dropdownvalue);

   WebElement clickdropdownvalue1 = findBy(selectdropdownvalue1);

   ((JavascriptExecutor) getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", clickdropdownvalue1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what's actually going on. A better description would help with examples. A screenshot of the section of the page would really help. Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use the proper xpath to select the required dropdown item.

Generic xpath:

```
(//ul[@role='listbox'][starts-with(@class,'ant-select-dropdown-menu')])[required index goes here]/li[@role='option'][.='country 1']
```

To Select `country 1` from the second downdown:

```
  (//ul[@role='listbox'][starts-with(@class,'ant-select-dropdown-menu')])[2]/li[@role='option'][.='country 1']
```